# Add usernames to database

Tags: ruby, html, sqlite, sinatra

I have this line in an .erb file to get the input of the username

```
<input type="text" placeholder="User Name" name="user[username]" value="<%#{@user.username}%>" class="form-control">
```

for my User.rb class I have the following:

```
class User
include DataMapper::Resource
property :id, Serial
property :username, String
property :password, String
property :role, String
end
DataMapper.finalize()

get '/users' do
@users = User.all
erb :users
```

Within users.erb I have the following

```
<div class="container">
<h3>Users</h3>
<% if @users.any? %>
  <ul <%#users%>>
    <% @users.each do |user|%>
         <li><%#{user.username}%></li>
    <%end%>
 <%else%>
  <p>No Users in database</p>
 <%end%>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

I want the to login a user and have that username stored in the database and then display that on the users page but it just keeps getting the else statement and I don't know why

Comment: Don't forget to indent your code properly especially when asking here. It communicates structure and intent.

Comment: I solved the problem, nvm